# Turning a private repository public

Tags: github

I have a dataset on a private GitHub repository that colleagues and I have been using for data analysis. We are now ready to publish the original dataset but *not* our code and analysis.

We want to share the data with others to make other analyses popular, but maintain a space where we can continue to work on things ourselves, withotu exposing our messy amateur code to the whole world.

What is best practices here? Should I just create a fork of the original repository and set it to be public? Then distribute that repo to the world?

Thank you for any suggestions.